# How to convert a large JSON file to CSV?

Tags: python, json, csv

I have some very large json files which i need to convert (The largest one is 4 gb). The online tools only support a small size which is not suitable for me.
So I looked to stackoverflow to look for scripts which may work for me. The found this one:

```
import csv
import json

infile = open("some.json","r")
outfile = open ("myfile1.csv","w")

writer = csv.writer(outfile)

for row in infile:
  data = json.loads(row)
  writer.writerow(data)
```

Here is a link one of my json files: https://pastebin.com/KwzgTzmP

When I run the file, I am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:/Users/Piyush/Desktop/2008/runcsv.py", line 11, in <module>
    writer.writerow(data)

_csv.Error: sequence expected
```

Can someone tell me how I can fix. I don't know python very well so I would appreciate if you give me a detailed answer.

Comment: Well, what you have got inside jour json documents is a complex, nested structure. There is no predefined way how this should look like as a flat CSV-based table. You need to define which parts of your json structure should form which columns of the csv.

Comment: You could clarify the structure of your json data if you create a short but representative excerpt from the large file. extra kudos if it's pasted into the question with proper formatting.

Comment: @PaulRooney I thought of doing that but the json entries are so long and complex that I gave up. Basically there are a lot of nested arrays and lists. When I used an online tool, I got nested field by adding an '_' between the names. For example, actors{ id:" "} was displayed as actors_id. This is what I would like to have in the program. However, my coding skills are extremely poor which is why for now, I am satisfied with just displaying the data in the csv. I'll think about formatting later .

Comment: @PaulRooney Also, do you know of any online or offline tool which can be used to convert a big json file?

Comment: You will not find a tool that just converts it, for the simple reason that @languitar states above. It's not as simple as just converting it, you need to know what format you are converting it to.  I suggest breaking your problem down to smaller problems. Is the file large and complex? Also the thing you ask about converting `actor: {id:""}` to `actor_id` seems like a valid question by itself.